# jAlbum Gallery - Slides Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the [jAlbum](http://jalbum.net/) program with the Lightflow Skin to create a gallery. Works well but when I attempt to navigate the gallery on my laptop and the images will slowly creep up and the titles will disappear. I cannot replicate this issue on my desktop, however, my screen size is large enough that the max image size does not override the screen size. This happens in Firefox (multiple versions) only. In Chrome and IE it displays correctly. Also the Close `X` is off to the left a bit too much (In all browsers on laptop only).

It would appear that the script is calculating the `top` property incorrectly.

Here is a bit of code:

```
<div id="lightwindow_container" style="height: 469px; width: 532px; left: -266px; top: -235px; display: block; visibility: visible;">
```

For the photos that go off the page if I change the `top` property I can make it fit the page without issue. (By changing it in Firebug when looking at the page.)

Here is a screenshot showing the issue:

[image: Screenshot of Errors]

[Here are the page(s) in question.](http://www.ubhape2.com/examples/month-1/#align-page)

How do I check and see if this is a script error or simply a local browser issue and how do I fix it if it is a script error?

Note: I would add the code but there is so much code it will reach the max limit allowed here in SO.